# Delete item of html table coming from input in JS DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jsdom, pure-js

I have problem with deleting operation in html table in JS. I trying to delete item of table which coming from input.It is nothing happen.

```js
const name = document.querySelector(".name");
const surname = document.querySelector(".surname");
const age = document.querySelector(".age");
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".addBtn");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".delete");
const tbody = document.querySelector(".tbl");

addBtn.addEventListener("click",addItem);
deleteBtn.addEventListener("click",deleteItem);

function addItem(e){
    var html = `<tr>
                    <td>${name.value}</td>
                    <td>${surname.value}</td>
                    <td>${age.value}</td>
                    <td class="delete">DELETE</td>
                </tr>`;
    if(name.value === '' || surname.value === '' || age.value === ''){
        alert("Warning!!!");
    }else{
        tbody.innerHTML += html;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
function deleteItem(e) {   
        if(e.target.className = 'delete'){
           e.target.parentElement.remove();
        } 
}
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Please Add your HTML code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/roop06/5w1psL6y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. The event listener is assigned to the first element that matches
   `'.delete'`, not all elements
2. Buttons that will be created via `addItem` won't have the listener attached to them

You can fix both by using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation): assign the listener on a common parent:

```
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", deleteItem)
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.tbl').addEventListener("click",deleteItem);` 
It is working. Thanks.
JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/roop06/5w1psL6y/

Answer (score 0):

Your table rows are added dynamically, you bind the event listener before the content is loaded into the dom(your row is added only when you call the `addItem` method). One way you can fix is, add event listener after appending content to the table every time.

Something like this

```
if(name.value === '' || surname.value === '' || age.value === ''){
     alert("Warning!!!");
}else{
     tbody.innerHTML += html;
     document.querySelector(".delete").addEventListener("click",deleteItem);
}
```